# Ceph FS PVC is auto unbound forcely

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc, cephfs, storage-class

I run 6 API pods with 1 deployments with k8s cluster and storage class of storage class.

When uploading files from api pods, The pvc mounted with API pods is auto unbound forcly.

There are no special logs in ceph cluster and other ceph daemons.

and There are no special logs of daemon and syslog too.

With manual Storage Class, Above problems don't occur.

What is the problem?

**My environment**

- os: debian 11.7(kernel: 5.10.0-23-amd64)
- k8s: v1.27.3, 1 control plane, 2 worker nodes
- cni: calico v3.26.1
- storage class: ceph fs v3.5.0
- ceph: 14.2.21
- cri: containerd 1.6.21-1

With CEPH fs Storage Class, 6 API Pods run well without unmount problem.